# R install.packages picks up wrong binary

Tags: r, install.packages

I do this:

```
options(repos = "http://corpserver.ru/r/")
install.packages("zoo")
```

and get the error:

```
... cannot open URL "http://corpserver.ru/r/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/zoo_1.8-
1.zip": HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

though there is no `zoo_1.8-1.zip` in `bin/windows/contrib/3.4/` folder on the server --- but there is `zoo_1.8-0.zip` (with zero at the end). So how to persuade R to install the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `devtools` to install a certain version

```
library(devtools)
install_version("zoo", version = "1.8-0")
```

You can also install the package by URL

```
URL <- "http://corpserver.ru/r/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/zoo_1.8-0.zip"
install.packages(URL, repos=NULL, type="source")
```